# How can I prevent Java 8/Tomcat 7 from URL encoding the URL Path on Response.sendRedirect

Tags: java, redirect, java-8, tomcat7, url-encoding

I have a fully localized site that has some characters in the URL path,
that are getting HTML encoded through the `Response.sendTemporaryRedirect` method:

```
String toReturn = /*StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(redirect)*/ redirect + "?" + URLEncoder.encode(json, "UTF-8");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");

java.net.URI location = new java.net.URI(toReturn);
return Response.temporaryRedirect(location).build();
```

The redirect is getting a 404 because the `"%C3%B1%C3%AD"` URL piece is being misinterpreted. Decoded, it looks like this: `ñí`.

I've tried `URLDecoder.decode(url, 'UTF-8')` and `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4` prior to the redirect with no luck. 
The code works fine othwerise.

Why is `javax.ws.rs.core.Response.sendTemporaryRedirect` URLEncoding the URL path?

Comment: Also, I've verified that the URI object has the correct path. It's definitely Response.temporaryRedirect

Comment: Another update, the HTTPServletResponse response also had the same problem. It seems to be at the servlet level.

Comment: which is the constructor of the response instance here?

Comment: The package for the Response is `javax.ws.rs.core.Response`, but this is also happening if I use the `HttpServletResponse`. There is no constructor.

Comment: Sorry, response is the `HTTPServletResponse` injected via `@Context`

Comment: I think you have to check the actual implementation of your JAX-RS provider. For example Apache CXF actually does a decoding. See [here](https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/8eab54c2a285ac91b0a04b8cd7e899d45f15b73a/rt/frontend/jaxrs/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/impl/ResponseBuilderImpl.java#L128)

Comment: Looks like a double encoding issue to me, can you post  a sample of `json`variable? Also, there's no parameter name after `"?"`, that can confuse the URI parser. Last, try the multi-param constructor to avoid the implicit parsing of the single param constructor `new URI("https", "some_host:port", "/", json, null)`.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the final url you want to redirect to, in an unencoded form?

Comment: You will need to give an example of what is your issue, because using the `HttpServletResponse` like `response.sendRedirect("http://your.domain:port/and/your/page?"+URLEncoder.encode(json,"utf-8"));` where json is a json, is ok.

Comment: Would be great to see debug info (i.e. the output of each line in the debugger) for your problematic data. That would really help with answering instead of just guessing.

Comment: It's helpful to extract a simple working code to simulate your case.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the "Location" response header to the string you want. It annoys me so much to see people fighting libraries when the core api is right there.